# Problem in initialising connection with Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to get to the Telegram API through Telethon Library. But I can't even start the connection. 
The code here is the sample code suggested in [the official guide](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/signing-in.html).

```
# Use your own values from my.telegram.org
api_id = ***
api_hash = '***'

# The first parameter is the .session file name (absolute paths allowed)
async with TelegramClient('new_session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I get the following error:

```
Please enter your phone (or bot token): 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AuthKeyUnregisteredError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py in is_user_authorized(self)
    190                 # Any request that requires authorization will work
--> 191                 await self(functions.updates.GetStateRequest())
    192                 self._authorized = True
```

...

```
AuthKeyUnregisteredError: The key is not registered in the system (caused by GetStateRequest)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-71009056fead> in async-def-wrapper()
      7     client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))
      8     client.run_until_disconnected()
----> 9 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py in __aenter__(self)
    634 
    635     async def __aenter__(self):
--> 636         return await self.start()
    637 
    638     async def __aexit__(self, *args):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py in _start(self, phone, password, bot_token, force_sms, code_callback, first_name, last_name, max_attempts)
    145             # Turn the callable into a valid phone number (or bot token)
    146             while callable(phone):
--> 147                 value = phone()
    148                 if inspect.isawaitable(value):
    149                     value = await value

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py in <lambda>()
     18     def start(
     19             self: 'TelegramClient',
---> 20             phone: typing.Callable[[], str] = lambda: input('Please enter your phone (or bot token): '),
     21             password: typing.Callable[[], str] = lambda: getpass.getpass('Please enter your password: '),
     22             *,

EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

The error suggests that:

```
The key is not registered in the system (caused by GetStateRequest)
```

But I got the app_id and api_hash from my.telegram.org.

Comment: "`async with` .. " or "`with` .. "? because you cant `async with` outside an async function

Comment: I tried that but it says:`RuntimeError: You must use "async with" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")`

Comment: are you importing 'telethon.sync' by any chance?

Comment: Nope. I'm using `telethon 1.14.0` with `Python 3.7.7`.